# Command not found shown along with correct exit status in Shell. How can this be fixed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel7

I am executing $? on a RHEL VM after a date or pwd command. I see the exit status is correct but it also returns 'command not found' error.

Tried some solutions from googling around but I didnt get a right solution.

This is how it looks like:

```
[root@xxxxxx yyyy]# pwd
/homes/yyyy
[root@xxxxxx yyyy]# $?
bash: 0: command not found
```

Only the exit status is shown. No other error is shown when executing the $? command.

Comment: `$?` is not a command, it is a variable containing the last exit code.

Comment: @SimonDoppler Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should write `echo $?`, since `$?` is not a shell command itself but a variable (value).

Answer (score 0):

"$?" is not a command, its a shell parameter, which  Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline. So you can pass it as a parameter to any function,process or store it to a variable for further usage.

You can get information about shell special parameters from the below link
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters

```
[root@xxxxxx yyyy]# pwd
/homes/yyyy
[root@xxxxxx yyyy]# echo $?

or 
[root@xxxxxx yyyy]# VAR1=$?
[root@xxxxxx yyyy]# echo $VAR1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference link.